# How to calculate number of trailing zeroes in given factorial

Tags: python, factorial

I am using below code for calculating trailing zeroes. It passes sample inputs, but it fails testcases. Can someone please point out the mistake in the code, so that I do not repeat it.

```
t = int(input())
#taking input for number of test cases
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    i = 1 
    lis = []
    while 5**i < n:
        lis.append((n//(5**i)))
        i += 1 
    print(sum(lis))
```

Following was sample input:
6
3
60
100
1024
23456
8735373

And it did return correct answers.

I have now realised what I had done wrong, in line 7, I wrote `while 5**i < n:` instead I shoud have wrote `while 5**i <= n:`

Only test cases where above code fails are 5^i.
This was my first question on stack overful, I am quite delighted by helpfulness  of the community.

Comment: Above code was based on this function z which says: sum [n/5^i] for i=1 till 5^i < n (where n is given factorial)

Answer (score 4):

The idea is good, but for exact powers of 5 it will go wrong.

For example `n=25`. As this has two factors of 5 (it is 5²), there is an extra trailing zero: while 24! has 4 trailing zeroes, 25! has 6 trailing zeroes. For each factor of 5 there is an extra zero. So similarly, 125! will have *three* zeroes more than 124! has.

So you need to *include* that exponent when `5**i == n` also. Note that there is no need for a list.

You could use this function:

```
# Returns the number of trailing zeroes in the 
# decimal representation of n! (the factorial of n)
def get_trailing_zeroes(n):
    zeroes = 0 
    while n > 0:
        n //= 5
        zeroes += n
    return zeroes
```

Comment: Thanks dear Sir, actually I had taken the exponent into acoount, thats where expresssion `5**i` comes in play. But I now found out that in while loop I set `5**i` strictly less than n, what should I have done is setting  `5**i` less than or equal to n. Only test cases above code failed are exponents of 5.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. Updated the answer accordingly.